# Int variable showing wrong value - Android

Tags: java, android, int

This code gives me wrong output, im not sure why, and I am going crazy.

```
    float correctX=((getWidth()/599)*x);
    float correctY=((getHeight()/740)*y);
```

The result I get is: x = 520
y = 900.

And logcat output log:  DETAILS----------Width: 1080. Heigth: 1533. X Value: 520. Y Value: 450

Why ? I have no clue and Im going crazy, i dont even know if its the correct syntax anymore lol.

I use android studio btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [integer division](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm) (go to *Confusing Divisions*) inaccuracies. Cast a few values to `float`s to make it better.

```
 int correctX = (int)((1080f/599)*520);
```

### OR

Just change `correctX` to a `float`

```
 float correctX = (1080f/599)*520;
```

Comment: Still incorrect.
This is how I write it:
        float correctX=((getWidth()/599)*x);
        float correctY=((getHeight()/740)*y);
This is the logcat output I get:

 DETAILS----------Width: 1080. Heigth: 1533. X Value: 520. Y Value: 450

Comment: That's because there are still no `float`s on the right hand of your assignment. It should be: ` float correctX=((getWidth()/599**f**)*x)` @JozefM

Comment: What does float s actually mean ?

Comment: What the hell, it works! 
Lol thanks alot!!!
Unsure what it means tho, some googling tells me it tells the system it should be a 32bit variable, but not sure why that makes a diffrence

Comment: Take a look at these: http://java.about.com/od/f/g/float.htm ---- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/floatingpoint-data-types-in-java.html @JozefM

Comment: The second link answerd my questions. Thank you Micheal, problems solved :)!